# How can i write a cron job code in php that substracts a number by some number everyday?

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

```
        <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user'";
        $help  = mysqli_query($database,$query);
        $row   = mysqli_fetch_array($help);

        $user_mangoes = $row['value'];
        $total_amount = round($user_amount - 5,2);

        if(login)
        {
        $update = "UPDATE users SET amount='$total_amount' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        $rent_update = mysqli_query($database,$update);
        }
        ?>
```

Eg Algorithm, 
Suppose i have 2000 mangoes and i eat 5 mangoes per day. i want the php logic to deduct 5 mangoes from the total mangoes. and update in the database. i want this  logic upto 30 days.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What you ask is very basic.

Comment: Apart from running the script once a day automatically (is that your question?), note that when running a cron-job, there is no notion of users / logins / sessions.

Comment: am sorry for the trouble but am a php noob. can you guys just write me a basic script that deducts and updates a number please just a basic one. Note: cron job once a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store your limit and/or 'used up' portion of the limit somewhere. The limit would be stored in a configuration or preferences table, the "used by this person" record would be added to the user's record.

If you have a limit of 30 days, put in a "day counter" and add one every day. Next up, if the limit is really "days" you'll need a "last day" value stored in another field for the user so you can tell if the present attempt represents a new day or if this is just a second execution on an "already run" day.

Comment: I understand this logically, but am not able to create the program, can you please write me a sample code, please thanks

Comment: This will require creating new fields to store those values. Field One: A preference field for what the limit is, probably not on the user record unless the limit is actually different per user. Field Two: "Used" for this user and/or "last day used" for this user. It's not about the code until after the fields exist.